# get the current k2 item ID

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, joomla-k2

I want to get the current item id from k2 and store it to a cookie.
(**Of course** when i wrote "the current item" I am in the item view of my k2 template.)

How can I get the item ID from K2?

I tried `$this->item->id` but seems it's not working.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Please remember we are not looking over your sholder. You are going to have to take a few minutes and add some detail if you want an answer.

Comment: It depends where you are. Is it an item view ? If so, $this->item->id should work. I've done it many times.

Comment: I was edited my Question. @RiggsFolly What more details i missing?

Comment: @Shaz, I will try this again. maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: @Shaz, Thanks, '$this->item->id' is working great.

Answer (score 3):

```
$K2Itemid = JRequest::getInt('id');
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT title FROM #__k2_items WHERE id = ".$K2Itemid );
$K2Catid = $db->loadResult(); 
echo $K2Catid;
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends where you are. Is it an item view ? If so, $this->item->id should work. I've done it many times.

Answer (score -2):

I agree with @shaz - this worked for me (item.php and category_item.php overrides):

```
<?php echo $this->item->id; ?>
```